# Properties and objects C#

Tags: c#, wpf, object, properties, datagrid

I want to make public property that gets and sets object I get from datagrid.
I have datagrid that has 3 columns with text and 3 columns with checkboxes. 
When I check one of the checkbox I get a value of whole row in list like this:

```
var selectedItemsController = MyObsCollection.Where(n => n.Controller).ToList();
```

That is a list of objects with all 3 string values (and all 3 bool values of checkboxes) that are in same row where checkboxes in column named Controller is.

MyObsCollection is also public property for ObservableCollection and they are defined like this:

```
ObservableCollection<RowData> _obsCollection =
                                new ObservableCollection<RowData>();
public ObservableCollection<RowData> MyObsCollection
{
   get { return _obsCollection; }
}
```

RowData is my class that caries a model I need and it's defined like this:

```
public class RowData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string MapTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Controller { get; set; }
    public bool Service { get; set; }
    public bool Injection { get; set; }

    public RowData(string type, string mapTo, string name) 
    {
        Type = type;
        MapTo = mapTo;
        Name = name;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a public property for that list of objects(in selectedItemsController) so I can use it in other class.

For example I was doing this with name for some Area that is also part of WindowsForm. I was taking the name from some text box and making public property like this:

```
public string AreaName
        {
            get { return AreaNameValue.Text; }
            set { AreaNameValue.Text = value; }
        }
```

And after that I was able to do this in other class:

```
var areaName = areaDialog.AreaName.Trim();
```

So finally my question is does someone know how can I make same public property for DataRow object if the name of DataGrid is for example: tabela? Is there something already defined in DataGrid that I can use? (like 'Text' property is for InputTextBoxes).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your selectedItemsController as the datacontext of your DataGrid. Then you can set and get values on the selectedItemsController itself.